# XSLT variable not act as nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one XML where some raw values are present as nodeset. i want to make it as variable and use in further process. Please look into below stuff:

**XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <element1>Some value in the element1</element1>
    <element2 value="&lt;sno&gt;1&lt;/sno&gt;&lt;name&gt;Amrendra&lt;/name&gt;&lt;mobile&gt;0123456789&lt;/mobile&gt;"></element2>
</root>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:variable name="element">
        <root>
            <xsl:value-of select="/root/element2/@value" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </root>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <root>
            <applytemp>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="$element/root/name"/>
            </applytemp>
            <copy-of>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$element/root/name"/>
            </copy-of>
            <value-of>
                <xsl:value-of select="$element/root/name"/>
            </value-of>
        </root>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**CURRENT OUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <applytemp/>
   <copy-of/>
   <value-of/>
</root>
```

**REQUIRED OUT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <applytemp>Amrendra</applytemp>
   <copy-of>Amrendra</copy-of>
   <value-of>Amrendra</value-of>
</root>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have one XML where some raw values are present as nodeset.

No, what you have is an escaped XML fragment represented as a string. Your attempt to unescape it using `disable-output-escaping` cannot work, because `disable-output-escaping` is performed only when writing to the output.

If your processor support XPath/XSLT 3.0, you can use the `parse-xml-fragment()` function to convert the string to a node tree:

**XSLT 3.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="3.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:variable name="elem2" select="parse-xml-fragment(/root/element2/@value)" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <root>
        <applytemp>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$elem2/name"/>
        </applytemp>
        <copy-of>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$elem2/name"/>
        </copy-of>
        <value-of>
            <xsl:value-of select="$elem2/name"/>
        </value-of>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
   <applytemp>
      <name>Amrendra</name>
   </applytemp>
   <copy-of>
      <name>Amrendra</name>
   </copy-of>
   <value-of>Amrendra</value-of>
</root>
```

---

**Demo**: https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdH2/2

---

In earlier versions you need to do this in two passes. First, unescape the string using `disable-output-escaping` and save the result to a file. Then process the resulting file.

Comment: XSLT 2.0 is also working. is it depending on version?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. `parse-xml-fragment()` is an Xpath 3.0 function. If it works, then the processor supports XSLT 3.0 (at least partly).

Answer (score 1):

change your variable declaration as below

```
<xsl:variable name="element">
    <root>
        <xsl:analyze-string select="//root/element2/@value" regex="&lt;([a-z]+)&gt;(.*?)&lt;/\1&gt;">
            <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:element name="{regex-group(1)}"><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(2)"/></xsl:element>
            </xsl:matching-substring>
        </xsl:analyze-string>
    </root>
</xsl:variable>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
   <applytemp>
      <name>Amrendra</name>
   </applytemp>
   <copy-of>
      <name>Amrendra</name>
   </copy-of>
   <value-of>Amrendra</value-of>
</root>
```

See transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5DZ

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 0):

Using disable-output-escaping when writing to a variable is a long-standing source of problems and controversy, known within the XSL WG as the "sticky-doe" problem. The XSLT 1.0 spec says (in §16.4)

*it is also an error to convert a result tree fragment to a number or a string if the result tree fragment contains a text node for which escaping was disabled.*

But Erratum E2 says:

*When a root node is copied using an xsl:copy-of element (see [11.3 Using Values of Variables and Parameters with xsl:copy-of]) and escaping was disabled for a text node descendant of that root node, then escaping should also be disabled for the resulting copy of that text node. For example*

```
<xsl:variable name="x">
  <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:copy-of select="$x"/>
```

*should output `<` not `&lt;`.*

That is, the disable-output-escaping property is "sticky": it survives in the variable and re-emerges when the copy is done.

This was reverted in XSLT 2.0: see appendix J.1.4, item 20:

*An erratum to XSLT 1.0 specified what has become known as "sticky disable-output-escaping": specifically, that it should be possible to use disable-output-escaping when writing a node to a temporary tree, and that this information would be retained for use when the same node was later copied to a final result tree and serialized. XSLT 2.0 no longer specifies this behavior (though it permits it, at the discretion of the implementation).*

Given this variation between specs, it's not going to be very predictable what a particular processor actually does in this situation. But then, it's always best to steer well clear of disable-output-escaping.